# Google Cloud Compute Engine with Gitlab Runner

Tags: gitlab, google-compute-engine

I am working on an image for a compute engine template to be used under a load balancer.
I have everything ready to go including a GitLab pipline that is triggered on a given branch merge.

My problem now is that I want this to run when a new instance is booted up.
This allows for the new instance to always be the most up to date code running.

I am using the gitlab api to trigger this pipeline using a start up script.
That is all working fine and well, however, part way through I get the following error

```
Session terminated, killing shell... ...killed.
ERROR: Job failed: aborted: terminated
```

The startup script for Compute Engine is as follows

```
sudo gitlab-runner register --non-interactive -u https://gitlab.com -r <token> --executor shell

curl --request POST --form token=<token> --form ref=feature/devops-auto-deploy https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/trigger/pipeline
```

This sets up the runner
Then runs triggers the pipeline

The same pipeline works when the server is up and running.
Is there some type of timeout on the google start up scripts?

Not sure what is happening here.
Any ideas?

thanks all

Comment: I would guess that gitlab-runner register is not able run just on startup.

On the gitlab documentation:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/google_cloud_platform/#installing-gitlab

The VM should spin first and then GitLab can be installed and configured on it.

The startup script just runs the command, I don't think there is a timeout for them. 

The only time-out I know of, is the 7 minutes one when the metadata server cannot be reached. 
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#troubleshooting

Comment: You could further check the startup script logs for more clues:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#viewing_startup_script_logs

Comment: I was actually able to fix it by adding a && between the two commands.  well that started working correctly once I did that